# Required message in SelectManyCheckbox componente

Tags: validation, jsf, required, selectmanycheckbox

I'm using JSF 2.1 with RichFaces 4 and I have a form with a `selectManyCheckbox` which I want it to have at least one item selected before processing the form.

I put to true the attribute `required` but no message appears when I click the submit button without selecting at least one checkbox.

How can I do that?

Cheers

**UPDATE**

```
                <a4j:outputPanel id="cargaDependencias">
                    <h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" required="true" 
                                          requiredMessage="Seleccione al menos una dependencia"
                                          disabled="#{administrationBean.loadAllDependencies}"
                                          value="#{administrationBean.selectedDependencies}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{administrationBean.loadSelectDependencies}"/>
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                </a4j:outputPanel>
                <br/><br/>

                <a4j:commandButton value="Actualizar Cubo"
                                   action="#{administrationBean.doUpdateInformationCube}"/>
```

Comment: I recommend you validate the checkbox selection with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach a `<h:message>` for the `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="dependencies" ...>
    ...
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
<h:message for="dependencies" />
```

The validation message will show in there.

When using ajax to submit the form, make sure that the `<h:message>` component(s) are also included in the ajax render/update.